# How to sort ckrecords by userID?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

How should I go about creating an nspredicate that checks the userID of a record in swift?

```
let userID = "__defaultOwner__"

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "keyToUseHere == %@", userID)
```

What should I put in place of the 'keyToUseHere' in the nspredicate to sort by the creator's id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the key which can be property of your model class something like this:-

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userID" == %@", userIDValue)
```